# how read custom page position

Tags: php

hi
I want a Read part of a site with php and save to new page to other site.(like weather.com)
I want this operation is the server side.
This is like a web crawler or robot!
Is this possible?
Updated several times a day get? such as cornjob

Comment: Hm, wonder if I should flag as offensive for "cornjob"...

Comment: Google baby Google! You might even find your answer on a page called [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2296465/web-crawler-parsing-php-javascript-links)

Comment: This is a very broad question. The process of fetching content from a web site is called "scraping" and has some answers e.g. here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523096/how-do-i-screen-scrape-a-website-and-get-data-within-div to do it frequently, you indeed want to look into cron jobs.

Comment: It may just be the user does not use English as a first language. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to get the webpage and parse it with [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) or [simple_html_dom](http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/)